# JBossESB - queue to service mapping

Tags: java, jboss-esb

I am intercepting messages that are sent through JBossESB. I am using pipeline interceptors to do so.

The problem is, that altough the sender is a service (for example *PortReference < logical:BlueServiceESB#BlueListener >*), the name of the receiver is a queue (not a service). That is logical because in some case, multiple services can receive messages from a given queue, but usually, each queue is mapped to only one service.

I would like to know which queue is mapped to which service, so I can display/save this information and have it displayed like **message: service ---> service** (not service ---> queue).

I know that I can get the name of the queue mapped to a service using the registry like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.registry.ConnectionFactoryClass", "org.apache.ws.scout.registry.ConnectionFactoryImpl");

// Retrieving information from the ESB Registry
Registry reg = RegistryFactory.getRegistry();
System.out.println(reg.findAllServices());
List<EPR> eprs = reg.findEPRs("FirstServiceESB", "SimpleListener");
System.out.println(eprs);
```

I would like to reverse this approach - queue is the input and service (EPR = end point reference = service) is the output. Is there any way how to do this or am I just trying to do the impossible here. I have found no tutorials or questions on this topic whatsoever.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JBoss ESB EPR data structure, but would querying for all of the queues and building a reverse-lookup map be an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such function that would allow searching for services using queue names :-(

Answer (score 1):

As this question has 25 up-votes, this seems to be an useful feature. JBossESB is open source software. Thus, implement the feature yourself and commit it to the community! Or just create a change request hopping that somebody else will do it...

Answer (score 0):

Try querying for all of the queues and building a reverse-lookup map. But I don't think there is any function that allows searching for services using a queue.